# How to set primary and foreign key relation in phpMyAdmin of GoDaddy

Tags: mysql, sql

There is no option of relation view in GoDaddy phpMyAdmin
so how do I set relation.
I tried manually by using query but it does not work.
Is there any way I can set relation between two tables.
Even there is no any solution on Google about GoDaddy phpMyAdmin.
If I'm working on local there is option of relation view but on godady there is no option.
How do I alter tables?

Working on this since last 2 hours and I'm new at this

I use this query for relation

```
ALTER TABLE co_pass_ticket_book
    ADD CONSTRAINT ticket_id_fk
    FOREIGN KEY (ticket_id)
    REFERENCES booking_table(ticket_id);
```

Comment: "i tried manually by using query but it does not work."What doesn't work is there a error?

Comment: "Doesn't work" won't help us help you.  What make it doesn't work???  Doesn't work now???  Execute but nothing happen???  Error out???

Comment: i have solved this